# Via MyBatis Interceptor adding current User Session Data as global parameter

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I would like to pass user session data (userId, IP, username, email and/or permissions, etc) while executing myBatis query.

I know that i am able to adding global variable. However I get error. It assumes my global paramater as a variable of model. How can I pass value and get and use it.

```
    @Intercepts({@Signature(
        type= Executor.class,
        method = "query",
        args = {MappedStatement.class, Object.class})})
public class ConfigPropInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private final Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    public Object intercept(Invocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        Object param = invocation.getArgs()[1];
        MappedStatement ms = (MappedStatement) invocation.getArgs()[0];
        Configuration configuration = ms.getConfiguration();
        configuration.getVariables().put("param", "value");

    return invocation.proceed();

    }
}
```

MyBatis Insert Call

```
<insert id="insertCity" parameterType="City" useGeneratedKeys="true" keyProperty="id">
    insert into city(name, state, country) values("${param}",#{state},#{country})
</insert>
```

Error

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no getter for property named 'param' in 'class com.project.data.model.City'
```

Comment: Try to remove `parameterType="City" `

Comment: It didn't work.